# Where is this controlling getting the request data from ? any documentation about it?

Tags: php, laravel

This is from the view

```
<a class="cambio_rutina waves-effect waves-light btn btn-success btn-margin" 
   data-url="{{route("changecode.rutina_general_simultaneo")}}"
   data-codigo="R01"
>
    Básica simultaneo
</a>
```

This is where i handle the request in the controller

```
public function rutina_general_simultaneo(Request $request)
{   
    if($request->ajax()) {
            $code = DB::table('codes')
                ->select('codes.*')
                ->where('codigo','ilike','%'.$request->codigo.'%')
                ->first();
    }
}
```

My question is. Does the `$request->codigo` part get the value from `data-codigo` attribute? Where can i learn more about this. I don't know how to search for this nothing comes up.

Comment: When you do `dd($request->codigo);` in your controller, do you see `data-codigo` value? Are you sure? If you try  `data-codigo="R01"` to  `data-codigo="Yordani"`, do you get Yordani?

Comment: Read the doc https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests

Comment: senty - I tried what you told me and changed the data-codigo="R01" to data-codigo="Yordani" and yes! I get "codigo" => "Yordani" in the request object in googles console Network tab using the dd($request->codigo) function you told me. Thank you! Your answer helped me confirm my question.

Answer (score 1):

Well basically `Request $request` is an object you can see it with making

```
dd($request);
```

on the first line in your controller method.

Being an object you can pull data from it if it's sent with that request.

The way the data ends up in that request is only with key names!!

There are 2 common ways of sending that data: 1. through html form with input fields where you need to set the name of that input OR 2. with sending ajax request with json where you also set `"key": "value"` pairs.

There are many ways to pull data from $request

If you want the whole array then use

```
$request->all();
```

If you want a certain key then use

```
$request['key'];
or
$request->input('key');
```

There is even a helper method `request()` which you can call where ever you want in laravel and get even more data from it e.g.

`request()->route()->parameters`

Comment: Does not answer my question but does provide good info thank you for taking the time to share! Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

My original question was not well written after re-reading this. It's no longer needed but just wanted to do an update to clarify. I was confused how the request object was getting the data from the html attribute data-codigo now I believe it has something to do with the other data-url and calling the route method. That way inside our controller we have access to this data-codigo attribute since we pass it along to the controller.